# jQuery - How can i slideDown a body append data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i click on #ams2t, everyting is working fine.. But how i can i slidedown images.html?

```
 $(document).on("click","#ams2t", function(){
       $.get( "images.html", function( data ) {
         $( "body" ).append( data );
      });
    });
```

I have tried this but that is not working:

```
 $(document).on("click","#ams2t", function(){
           $.get( "images.html", function( data ) {
             $( "body" ).append( data ).slideDown( "slow");
          });
        });
```

Comment: Isn't the data already appeared? I believe `slideDown` only works with hidden elements

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the html received from server before it is inserted. The new html has to first be hidden in order to make slideDown possible

```
$.get( "images.html", function( data ) {
        var $newHtml = $(data).hide();
        $( "body" ).append( $newHtml );
        $newHtml.slideDown()
});
```

If there isn't a root element to hide ... use `wrap()` to give it an outer container to hide